# Laravel error in query that has "as having"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

At all query in laravel is error

> Syntax error or access violation: 1463 Non-grouping field 'distanse' how this itself query use in mysql this is all good

Syntax error or access violation: 1463 Non-grouping field 'distanse' is used in HAVING clause (SQL: SELECT city, (6371*acos(cos(radians(51.2465)) * cos(radians(x)) * cos(radians(y)
- radians(22.5684)) + sin(radians(51.2465)) * sin(radians(x)))) as distanse from city having distanse < ''
)

Comment: and what is the query that threw this error?

Comment: Can you give an example of the way you are building the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error or access violation: 1463 Non-grouping field 'distanse' is used in HAVING clause (SQL: SELECT city, (6371*acos(cos(radians(51.2465)) * cos(radians(x)) * cos(radians(y)
- radians(22.5684)) + sin(radians(51.2465)) * sin(radians(x)))) as distanse from city having distanse < ''
)

Answer (score 0):

Use `WHERE` clause instead of `HAVING`. What I can see from your query

> Syntax error or access violation: 1463 Non-grouping field 'distanse'
>   is used in HAVING clause (SQL: SELECT city,
>   (6371*acos(cos(radians(51.2465)) * cos(radians(x)) * cos(radians(y) -
>   radians(22.5684)) + sin(radians(51.2465)) * sin(radians(x)))) as
>   distanse from city having distanse < '' )

you are not aggregating or grouping elements.

Comment: Use and add error Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distanse' in 'where clause' ...

Comment: This is because `select` clause aliases do not work in `where` clause. You can refer to order of Sql statements in which they are executed

Comment: so what should I do ?